# How can I write $1/n^2$ as a product of n terms $c_1,....,c_n$ in such a way that $c_n$ tends to a limit $\neq 0$?

Tags: number-theory

How can I write $\frac{1}{n^2}$,for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 1$, as a product of n terms $c_1,....,c_n$ in such a way that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}c_n\neq 0$?

Comment: Suppose that $c_1\cdot c_2\cdots c_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$.  What would $c_{n+1}$ need to be to get $\left(c_1\cdot c_2\cdots c_n\right)\cdot c_{n+1}=\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\cdot c_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$?  If you use this pattern for all values of $c_i$ do you get what you want?

Answer (score 1):

$c_n=\frac{c_1c_2\cdots c_n}{c_1c_2\cdots c_{n-1}}=\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}}=\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}$, with $c_1=1$.

Comment: @Quaternione Come on, $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=1$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac1{n^2}
=\dfrac1{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{n-k}{n-(k-1)}
$

Answer (score -2):

Put $c_n=1$ and $c_j=n^{\frac{-2}{n-1}}$ for $j=1,2,\dots, n-1$.

Comment: Are the $c_i$ supposed to be independent of $n$?

Comment: No, because It is impossible for a product of numbers independent of $n$ to be a function of $n$.

Comment: The requirement is that $c_1 \cdots c_n = 1/n^2$ for each $n$. See some of the other answers here.

Comment: @anomaly - last time I checked, the product of $1$ and $n^{\frac{-2}{n-1}}$ multiplied by itself $n-1$ times is precisely $1/n^2$. As a non-too-deep consequence of this fact, my example meets the requirement. I am so sorry this computation escapes you, so you keep making irrelevant comments.